# What types of leaks get reported in logcat and what other ways or tools do we have for finding leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, logcat

I'm beginning Android development and I am concerned about leaks.

I think thread leaks can get reported in logcat if memory serves. But what other types of leaks get reported by logcat? I have gotten feedback about potential leaks that concerns me and I take it very seriously.

What other ways do I have for detecting leaks? For example can I instrument my code so that an otherwise unnoticeable leak will show up in logcat?

Thanks for any reply. Happy coding.

Comment: If you care to elaborate on "I have gotten feedback about potential leaks that concerns me"

Comment: @DallaRosa I was talking with someone about calling static methods from threads and they said that leads to leaks. Good luck with your ventures in Japan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great talk at IO this year on the subject http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html

Comment: I liked the answer. If you liked my question consider voting it up as I voted up your answer.

Comment: @Marie you got it, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

There's the Allocation Tracker tool in DDMS, that goes down to a very detailed level. Here's some info from Romain Guy (one of the folks on the Android dev team at Google):

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/07/track-memory-allocations-on-android/

Extremely valuable tool.